# How to publish game

Tags: python

I have made a game using python and converted it into an EXE file. My program requires an addition folder named as Assets and so to make my program work I always have to keep my EXE file and the Assets folder in the same folder. Now I wanted to publish my game to Microsoft Store and even completed all the necessary steps required like- payment, etc. But when it comes to upload my game to finish with publishing then I face a problem that I can only upload my game which is in msix,msixupload,xap etc, but my game is contained in a folder and if I convert my game into msix format then the required folder(Assets) would be missing and my game wouldn't work. So I either have to convert the main folder in to msix format or any other file format supported my Microsoft Publisher page or find out any other way. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you found an answer useful or correct, then make sure to upvote it & click the checkmark icon on the left of it. This marks it as valid and proves that it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are packaging your game with PyInstaller, then you can use the `--add-data` option to package your folder with the .exe file. More information can be found [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search), but here's the command syntax:

```
--add-data <SRC;DEST or SRC:DEST>
```

If you want to package the folder "Assets" with your .exe file, and upon running, have the folder "Assets" drop next to the file, then you'd package the python script with the following option:

```
--add-data Assets:Assets
```

Comment: I have tried this method but it gives me an error - "argument --add-data: invalid add_data_or_binary value: 'Assets:Assets' " and I watched few tutorials who showed the same thing as yours but they still need to keep the dependency folder that is "Assets" in my case with the exe file always and I just want a single exe.